# Firebase iOS Swift - Adding Atname Update Function to Settings

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

Using Firebase and Swift, I am attempting to update the "atname" data in Firebase. Currently, the function is currently set up to modify the "username" and "bio" sections in Firebase. The following code is in my SettingsViewModel.swift file:

```
func updateDetails(field: String){
        alertView(msg: "Update \(field)") { (txt) in
            
            if txt != ""{
                self.updateBio(id: field == "Name" ? "username" : "bio", value: txt)
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    func updateBio(id: String, value: String){
        ref.collection("Users").document(uid).updateData([
        
            id: value,
        ]) { (err) in
            if err != nil{return}

            fetchUser(uid: self.uid) { (user) in
                self.userInfo = user
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*"username" is the name inside of the Firebase database. "Name" is added before the ? to provide a better understanding in alertView on what the user is updating.*

Here is the code inside my SettingsView.swift file: (The part that is seen on the app)

```
  HStack(spacing: 15){
                
                Text(settingsData.userInfo.username)
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                
                Button(action: {settingsData.updateDetails(field: "Name")}) {
                    Image(systemName: "pencil.circle.fill") //makes text off centered, figure out how to fix
                        .font(.system(size: 24))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
            
            HStack(spacing: 15){
                
                Text(settingsData.userInfo.atname)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                
                Button(action: {settingsData.updateDetails(field: "Atname")}) {
                    Image(systemName: "pencil.circle.fill") //makes text off centered, figure out how to fix
                        .font(.system(size: 24))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
            .padding()

            HStack(spacing: 15){
                
                Text(settingsData.userInfo.bio)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                
                Button(action: {settingsData.updateDetails(field: "Bio")}) {
                    Image(systemName: "pencil.circle.fill") //makes text off centered, figure out how to fix
                        .font(.system(size: 24))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
```

As you can see, inside of SettingsView.swift, my field for the Atname section is "Atname". However, in SettingsViewModel.swift, I can not figure out how to add Atname into the code to get Atname to actually update in Firebase.

Any time I try to add "Atname" I end up with some kind of error. If launch the app and try to edit "Atname" in settings, it changes "bio". I am relatively new to Swift and I have no idea how to get this to work.

Any help will be appreciated! I can provide more code/details if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, because of the ternary expression that you're using, the only two possibilities for `id` are "username" or "bio".

I'd suggest refactoring `updateDetails` so that it can accept more types of input. I see that you're also displaying a message `alertView`, which looks like the reason you're trying to convert the actual field name into something more human readable -- I added another function called `readableNameForField` that uses a `switch` statement to provide the readable names.

What about something like this?

```
func readableNameForField(_ field : String) -> String {
  switch field {
    case "username":
      return "Name"
    case "atname":
      return "At Name"
    default:
      return field.localizedCapitalized
  }
}

func updateDetails(field: String){
  alertView(msg: "Update \(readableNameForField(field))") { (txt) in
    if !txt.isEmpty {
      self.updateBio(id: field, value: txt)
    }
  }
}
```

Then, at your call sites, you'd use the actual field names:

```
settingsData.updateDetails(field: "username")
settingsData.updateDetails(field: "atname")
settingsData.updateDetails(field: "bio")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try this a bit later. I was researching in the Swift documentation and I read something about ternary expressions - a ? b : c. However, I had no idea what to replace it with. Thank you so so much!

Comment: Once you've had a chance to check it out, if it works for you, you can mark it as correct/accepted using the green checkmark.